# How to get number of users registered in firebase inside a fragment?

Tags: android, firebase, android-fragments, firebase-realtime-database

The following method I have used to retrieve the number of user accounts in my firebase database. It is working fine when I use an activity. But when I use the same method in a fragment, the app will crash. What are the modifications to do?

```
private void loadDetails() {
        DatabaseReference ref= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
        ref.orderByChild("accountType").equalTo("User").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                userList.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                    ModelUsers modelUsers=ds.getValue(ModelUsers.class);
                    userList.add(modelUsers);
                }
                cusValueTv.setText(userList.size());

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Logcat as follows,

```
2020-08-01 16:28:34.048 3697-3697/com.myproject.marutiVendor E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myproject.marutiVendor, PID: 3697
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x19
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:360)
        at android.content.res.MiuiResources.getText(MiuiResources.java:97)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5873)
        at com.myproject.marutiVendor.DashboardFragment$2.onDataChange(DashboardFragment.java:92)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(ValueEventRegistration.java:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(DataEvent.java:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(EventRaiser.java:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting a numeric value to the text view in this line:

```
cusValueTv.setText(userList.size());
```

Android maps this call to this [method signature](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setText(int)):

> `setText(int resid)`

> Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.

So it goes looking for a resource with that numeric ID. The reason this is helpful, is that you can then provide translations of the text in resource bundles for different languages.

None of this applies to your scenario of course, as you're actually trying to just display the number itself, and not a resource. To call the correct version of `setText`, you can just convert the number to a string in your call:

```
cusValueTv.setText(userList.size().toString());
```

Or alternatively:

```
cusValueTv.setText("" + userList.size());
```

Comment: cannot add .tostring to the following line.It is useless

Comment: "cannot add .tostring to the following line.It is useless " That is a bit hard to act on. Why can't you? What is going wrong when you do this? I also added an alternative way to convert the number to a string.